# Determining the recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am having trouble with this problem. I am trying to see if I am doing this properly, and it would be very helpful if someone could check my work.

Here is the problem:

A piece of paper is 1 inch thick.  By folding it in half, the thickness becomes 2 inches.  Folding into half again, its thickness becomes 4 inches,..

1. What recurrence relation is indicated?
2. What is the thickness of the paper after it is folded 10 times?

For 1, I did the following: $1,2,4,8,16\dots$ , $a_n=2^n$, $a_n=a_{n-1}\times2$, $a_1=1$.

For 2, I did the following: $1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512$, therefore the thickness of the paper after it is folded $10$ times is $512$ inches?

Comment: Miscounted by one fold.

Comment: Oh, for number 2?

Comment: For the second part the thickness of the paper should be 1024 inches if you fold it 10 times.

Comment: I would rather call the initial thickness of the paper $a_0$. And yes, ir is for the second question.

Comment: Oh..so the first term is really a_0, not a1.

Comment: Yes because when you fold 1 time, it's already 2 inches.

Comment: Oh, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

1. a<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup> , a<sub>n-1</sub> *2, a<sub>1</sub> =1
2. 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024, therefore the thickness of the paper after it is folded 10 times is 1024 inches.